# How to add a screen onto another screen in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, python-3.5

I'm trying to make a screen that has two rows, one of those rows are the actual game screen and the another one is a button to clear the table above. But the problem here is that the first row is blank when I run the app. That's the code that I am stuck till now:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

kivy.require('1.9.2')


class VelhaGame(GridLayout, Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(VelhaGame, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 3
        self.rows = 3
        self.font_size = 100

        self.buttons = []

        for i in range(9):
            button = Button(text='', font_size=self.font_size)
            button.bind(on_release=self.player_turn)
            self.add_widget(button)
            self.buttons.append(button)

        self.player1 = True

    def player_turn(self, button, *args):
        if self.player1 and button.text == '':
            self.player1 = False
            button.text = 'X'
        elif not self.player1 and button.text == '':
            self.player1 = True
            button.text = 'O'


class MainMenu(GridLayout, Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainMenu, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.rows = 2
        self.button_play = Button(text='PLAY', font_size=40)
        self.button_play.bind(on_release=self.play)
        self.add_widget(self.button_play)
        self.button_exit = Button(text='EXIT', font_size=40)
        self.button_exit.bind(on_release=self.exit)
        self.add_widget(self.button_exit)

    def play(self, *args):
        screen_manager.current = 'velhaPage'

    def exit(self, *args):
        App.get_running_app().stop()

game_screen_manager = ScreenManager()
game_screen_manager.add_widget(VelhaGame(name='velhaGame'))


class VelhaScreen(GridLayout, Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(VelhaScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rows = 2
        self.add_widget(game_screen_manager)
        self.clear_button = Button(text='Clear', font_size=40)
        self.add_widget(self.clear_button)

screen_manager = ScreenManager()
screen_manager.add_widget(MainMenu(name='menu'))
screen_manager.add_widget(VelhaScreen(name='velhaPage'))


class VelhaGameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return screen_manager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    VelhaGameApp().run()
```

Do you know what I could do to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to you question, is "You cannot do that".
Screenmanager only shows one screen at a time.

you can read about that in the docs https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html

But to acheive something like you are trying to, you could do like this:

Instead of screens inside another screen, you could put the gridlayout, and button inside a vertical orientated boxlayout like this:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ListProperty

kivy.require('1.9.1')


class VelhaGame(Screen):

    buttons = ListProperty([])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(VelhaGame, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.game_window = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        self.add_widget(self.game_window)

        self.game_table = GridLayout(cols=3,rows=3)

        for i in range(9):
            button = Button(text='', font_size="100sp")
            button.bind(on_release=self.player_turn)
            self.game_table.add_widget(button)
            self.buttons.append(button)

        self.player1 = True

        self.clear_button = Button(on_press=self.clear,text='Clear', font_size="40sp")

        self.game_window.add_widget(self.game_table)
        self.game_window.add_widget(self.clear_button)


    def clear(self,*args):
        for button in self.buttons:
            button.text = ""


    def player_turn(self, button, *args):
        if self.player1 and button.text == '':
            self.player1 = False
            button.text = 'X'
        elif not self.player1 and button.text == '':
            self.player1 = True
            button.text = 'O'


class MainMenu(GridLayout, Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainMenu, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.rows = 2
        self.button_play = Button(text='PLAY', font_size="40sp")
        self.button_play.bind(on_release=self.play)
        self.add_widget(self.button_play)
        self.button_exit = Button(text='EXIT', font_size=40)
        self.button_exit.bind(on_release=self.exit)
        self.add_widget(self.button_exit)

    def play(self, *args):
        screen_manager.current = 'velhaPage'

    def exit(self, *args):
        App.get_running_app().stop()


screen_manager = ScreenManager()
screen_manager.add_widget(MainMenu(name='menu'))
screen_manager.add_widget(VelhaGame(name='velhaPage'))


class VelhaGameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return screen_manager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    VelhaGameApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I completely forgot about that. The changes that you've made did the magic, now I can go back to the improvement of this game. By the way, is there a way to use transitions with the box layout like the screen does?

Comment: @MatheusFernando The screens have transitions when switching between them. Where do you want transitions? When the text on the buttons changes?

Comment: I would like to have a transition in a single box of the box layout, for example, when clicking the clear button, the game table dashes to the side and a new table comes with this transition.

Comment: @MatheusFernando look at kivy.animation https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.animation.html